# Creating and traversing dataframe in a top down approach

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a complex problem at hand to solve.
Data is in pandas dataframe and is stored like

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si3zr.png)

For each value in level3, I have calculated a metric and the next step is to create a structure (the output can be a simple list too)
Where we traverse from level1 and go to level3 (top down approach).
The output can be visualized like:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahe9Q.png)

Eg: we start with aa in level 1 and observe that aa has 3 children(level2).
Now based on the metric, we group and identify that abc is best when separate and (def,ghi) can be clubbed.
Basically in order to come up with that, we have to try all combinations from level2 and then pick the best one.

I have a function which does go from level1 to level2. But it needs to go to level3 recursively.

Here's the logic which I have at present:

function1:

1. creates the table with all the combinations from level2
2. calculates the score based on all combinations and pick the lowest one(lower the better)
3. if lowest score< parent score:

   ```
   go to that combination and further try to split it
   ```

   else:

   ```
   that node is the terminal node
   ```
4. Step 3 goes in a loop and splits the level 2 into the output shown
5. For each of the step4 split, identify and split it's level3 children similarly using the same logic

I am having hard time in passing the output of step4 into step5

Comment: Please don't provide examples of your output as pictures. We cannot copy, edit, modify, etc. those pictures which makes it more difficult to help.